# Quick and dirty operator!=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In my classes I often write a quick `operator!=` by returning `!(*this == rhs)`, e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int n_;
    std::string str_;
public:
    ...
    bool operator==(const Foo& rhs) const
    {
        return n_ == rhs.n_ && str_ == rhs.str_;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Foo& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
};
```

I can't see any obvious problems with doing this but thought I'd ask if anyone knows of any.

Comment: +1 for still liking operator overloading and not IsEqual(ObjA,ObjB). I find this neat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that's the preferred method of implementing `operator!=` so that you don't repeat yourself, and you have a guaranteed correct relationship with `operator==`.

Answer (score 3):

Defining `operator!=` as `!operator==` is just fine

For getting these trivial equivalent operators easily defined, I always use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).

The case with only `operator==` and `operator!=` (i.e. using [equality_comparable<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#equality_comparable2)) doesn't gain very much.

But when you need less and greater than too, or some combination of `operator+`, `operator*` etc. this becomes very convenient.

An example for your case would read

```
class Foo : private boost::equality_comparable< Foo >
{
   private:
     int n_;
     std::string str_;
   public:
     ...
   bool operator==(const Foo& rhs) const
   {
      return n_ == rhs.n_ && str_ == rhs.str_;
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's absolutely fine - I do exactly the same.